# Deferred execution vs deferred **data source** evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-objects, deferred-execution

I'm a big fan of deferred execution and all that jazz, but now I got slightly different problem.

Consider the following first naïve implementation of a process monitor that simply displays all the processes running on the current machine sorted by StartTime:

```
public partial class ProcessesByStartTimeForm : Form {

    // ... init stuff

    public static readonly IEnumerable<object> ProcessQuery
        = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
          let startTime = Eval.TryEvalOrDefault<DateTime?>(() => p.StartTime)
          orderby startTime
          select new {
              Process = p.ProcessName,
              StartTime = startTime, // could be null
              Title = p.MainWindowTitle
          };

    private void ProcessesByStartTimeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.RefreshDataSource();
    }

    private void refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.RefreshDataSource();
    }

    private void RefreshDataSource() {
        this.gridView.DataSource = ProcessQuery.ToList();
    }
}
```

(NOTE: the `Eval.TryEvalOrDefault<T>(Func<T> f)` is just a helper method that I use to evaluate stuff that might throw an exception and return `default(T)` instead).

Now the thing is that the data source is evaluated only once, precisely at the formation of the query.

And yes, I know, I could just wrap this query definition within a method that keeps recreating it over and over, but I think you can get that my point is to get some-sort of neat trick to make the evaluation of a data-source dynamic, every time that the query is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HA... I think we could pretty much apply the same trick as in the let clause... Define a wrapper that evaluates a `Func<IEnumerator<T>>` at runtime too!

```
public partial class ProcessesByStartTimeForm : Form {

    // ... init stuff

    public static readonly IEnumerable<object> ProcessQuery
        = from p in new DeferredEnumerable<Process>(() => Process.GetProcesses())
          let startTime = Eval.TryEvalOrDefault<DateTime?>(() => p.StartTime)
          orderby startTime
          select new {
              Process = p.ProcessName,
              StartTime = startTime, // could be null
              Title = p.MainWindowTitle
          };

    class DeferredEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
        readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> f;

        public DeferredEnumerable(Func<IEnumerable<T>> f) {
            this.f = f;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
            return this.f().GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```